# How to replace unity with gnome from USB

Tags: unity, system-installation, ubuntu-gnome, usb-installation

so i've been using unity for a while and it's alright but I have been looking at other environments such as gnome and mate. I created the bootable pen drives for gnome and I was wondering if there is any way to install gnome using the pen-drive( i really do not want to use software center or terminal) to completely replace unity but still keep my data. I know that i can do it from the terminal and i have done it but i couldn't get rid of unity completely. When I tried last time the installation ended up crashing and breaking and i had to erase my hard drive completely and reinstall and start all over again.

ps- been using linux for like 3 weeks now so i'm not yet a professional. At the moment i'm on ubuntu unity 16.04.

Comment: so... you want to download the GNOME packages by hand, put them on a thumbdrive, and install them manually, instead of using the provided package management tools?   it's possible, but more work.  http://packages.ubuntu.com search for `gnome-desktop`.  don't forget any dependencies!  good luck!

Comment: No matter if you use an USB or not, the fastest, easiest and safest way involves using the terminal.